# XAML: Show button on ComboBox item highlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate

I have a ComboBox with an `ItemTemplateSelector`, using 2 different `DataTemplate`s, one for when its drop down is visible and another when it is not. For the drop down template, each ComboBox item is represented by a `TextBlock` and a `Button` that should only be visible whenever that item is focused/highlighted/mouse over. This is what I've tried:

```xml
    <ComboBox x:Name="Windows" ItemsSource="{Binding Windows}" SelectedItem="{Binding Window}" Focusable="False" MaxDropDownHeight="238">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
            <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
                <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleShort}" ToolTip="{Binding Title}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.SelectedTemplate>
                <s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">                        
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleShort}" />
                            <Button Content="X">
                                <Button.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=Windows}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Button.Style>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector.DropDownTemplate>
            </s:ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignComboBoxItemStyle}" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
```

```cs
    public class ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate SelectedTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate DropDownTemplate { get; set; }
    
        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = GetVisualParent<ComboBoxItem>(container);
    
            if (comboBoxItem == null)
            {
                return SelectedTemplate;
            }
    
            return DropDownTemplate;
        }
    
        private static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
        {
            DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    
            while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
            {
                child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            }
    
            return child as T;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you also paste definition of `s` and `ComboBoxItemTemplateSelector`

Comment: @LeiYang I dont think that's so important as it just wraps a `DataTemplate`, but anyways I've updated the question. The problem is all about the `DataTrigger`'s binding to represent the current highligheted item.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox generates ComboBoxItem as a container for every item in its itemssource. You can bind to its properties with RelativeSource binding.

This should get you the expected behavior:

```
        <Button Content="X">
          <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
              <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```